# elements center of circle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design rounded login form as below. To do that I need to align center vertically and horizontally.

I make outer dive as relative and inner div as absolute. But still, elements are in outside of the circle. Please ignore my elements style.

[image]

My code,

```css
.login-container{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;    flex-wrap: nowrap;    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;display: table; 

}

.login-circle
{
    background-color: aqua;  margin: auto;
    border: solid 10px blue;
    color: #555555;
    border-radius: 50%;
   
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}


.centerXY {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.pos-a{
    position: absolute;
}
.pos-r{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-circle pos-a centerXY">
    <div class="login-contant pos-r" style="width:120px;height:120px">

      <div class="pos-r centerXY">
        <div class=" pos-a centerXY">
          <span>Sign In</span>
          <input placeholder="Username">
          <input placeholder="Password">        
          <button>Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)? It's an easy way to design flexible responsive layout structure.

CSS:

```
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Text</div>
  <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to set position of inner div(pos-r) as fixed to get elements into the circle**

```css
.login-container{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;    flex-wrap: nowrap;    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;display: table; 

}

.login-circle
{
    background-color: aqua;  margin: auto;
    border: solid 10px blue;
    color: #555555;
    border-radius: 50%;
   
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}


.centerXY {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.pos-a{
    position: absolute;
}
.pos-r{
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-circle pos-a centerXY">
    <div class="login-contant pos-r" style="width:120px;height:120px">

      <div class="pos-r centerXY">
        <div class=" pos-a centerXY">
          <span>Sign In</span>
          <input placeholder="Username">
          <input placeholder="Password">        
          <button>Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `display:flex` and `align-items:center` you can achieve this. i have made changes in below CSS class and removed inline `height` and `width` from HTML.

```
.pos-r {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.login-container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
}

.login-circle {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 10px blue;
  color: #555555;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.centerXY {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pos-a {
  position: absolute;
}

.pos-r {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-circle pos-a centerXY">
    <div class="login-contant pos-r">

      <div class="pos-r centerXY">
        <div class=" pos-a centerXY">
          <span>Sign In</span>
          <input placeholder="Username">
          <input placeholder="Password">
          <button>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it with flexbox:

```css
.login-container{
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.login-circle
{
    background-color: aqua;  margin: auto;
    border: solid 10px blue;
    color: #555555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
    
.flex{   
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-circle">
    <div class="flex">
      <span>Sign In</span>
      <input placeholder="Username">
      <input placeholder="Password">        
      <button>Login</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```